# Message card posting to target returns blank from teams input

Tags: webhooks, microsoft-teams, office365connectors

I am trying to get some information from user via cards, the target url is receiving a blank post request instead of user input.Here is the code

```
requests.post(url="incoming webhook",
json=
{
    "@type": "MessageCard",
    "@context": "http://schema.org/extensions",
    "summary": "John Doe",
    "title": "input",
    "potentialAction": [
      {

        "@type": "ActionCard",
        "name": "Change status",
        "inputs": [{
            "@type": "MultichoiceInput",
            "id": "list",
            "title": "Select a status",
            "isMultiSelect": "true",
            "style":"compact",

            "choices": [{
                "display": "OBE",
                "value": "OBE"
            }, {
                "display": "OUI",
                "value": "OUI"
            }, ]
        }],
        "actions": [{
            "@type": "HttpPOST",
            "name": "Save",
            "target": "aworkingurl",

        }]

      }]})
```

The url that I used is from a site called webhooks.site which gives urls that accept POST and GET requests, the site shows that a POST has been attempted but the content is empty but when I posted some string to the same url it show that data just fine.

Comment: this is probably NOT the problem, but your JSON has an error - "  }, ] " before "actions"

Comment: Where/how is this message card being sent to the team channel?

Comment: I am ```req.post```ing using the incoming webhook configured in a teams channel and the above is the JSON load. I have missed the braces in copy pasting i'll edit the code to include the whole block of code

Comment: Hi,resolved the problem in actions body variable is required below target ```"target": "aworkingurl",
            "body":"Campaign:{{list.value}}" ```

Comment: Hey I was using a temporary solution(an online service which gives free URL for a limited time) as a target URL while testing, now how/where can I get a permanent target URL to collect my data.

Comment: there are a ton of options for this, it depends what you want to do. An example is an Azure Function or AWS Lambda